# why Array of Float64Array is taking so much memory in Node.js?

Tags: arrays, node.js, memory, memory-management

Found a very interesting situation, node.js 6.11.0, Win 10. After running this code

```
function rand() {return Math.floor(Math.random()*10);}
let s = new Array(10000000).fill(0).map(a => new Float64Array([rand(), rand()]));
```

and calling `global.gc()` few times, the node.js environment was taking 1,7GB of space. I have no explanation of this - Float64Array of two numbers is taking 16bytes, times 10000000 is ~160MB. Even if you assume that each element of array `s` is actually a pointer to Float64Array, which is another 8 bytes, it makes 240MB, but not 1,7GB for sure.

What could be the explanation to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `node --inspect` (Node 9.5.0) output for

```
function rand() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
}
const arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    arr.push(new Float64Array([rand(), rand()]));
    if(i % 1000 == 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

global.x = arr;
```

it looks like each of those `Float64Array`s of 2 items requires 208 bytes of memory, so there's "simply" a significant per-object overhead there.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome inspector]

If you need something like this, I'd suggest allocating a single flat `Float64Array` of 2 * 10000000 items and indexing into it.  (FWIW, I just tried that: the single 200-million-item Float64Array consumes 600 megabytes of memory and the allocation and execution near-instant.)